# Is there a way to pass a sequential value for a varargs function?

Tags: clojure

If you call a vararg function with a list you get a list of the list, which makes perfect sense.

```
(defn foo
  [& bar])

(foo 1 2 3) ;; bar = (1 2 3)
(foo '(1 2 3)) ;; bar = ((1 2 3))
```

Other than a macro to splice the list into the foo form, is there a way to call foo with '(1 2 3) such that bar is (1 2 3)?

For example, you can call varargs with an array or varargs:

```
class Foo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        varargs(1, 2, 3);
        int[] varargs = new int[]{3, 4, 5};
        varargs(varargs);
    }

    public static void varargs(int... varargs) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(varargs));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what apply does:

```
user> (defn foo [ & stuff]
        (println (reverse stuff)))
#'user/foo
user> (apply foo [1 2 3])
(3 2 1)
```